# elseif statement with html inside!! help?

Tags: php, if-statement

So, call me new. I am struggling to see what i have to do here. Ive been looking for hours, decided to ask you guys.

I am trying to show a link class of "gthumb" when var=1. When it is 2, i want to have no class for the link tag.

This is calling for an image to be put into lightbox for an image gallery.

```
<?php if ($link == '1') {?>
<a class="gthumb" href="<?php echo $img_url; ?>" title="<?php echo $img_title; ?>"> 

<?php elseif ($link == '2') {?>
<a href="<?php echo $img_url; ?>" title="<?php echo $img_title; ?>"> 
<?php endif; ?>

<img class="<?php echo $img_class; ?>" src="<?php echo $img_preview; ?>" alt="<?php echo $img_alt; ?>" title="<?php echo $img_title; ?>" />
<?php if ($link == '1,2') : ?>
</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Change this line:

```
<?php if ($link == '1,2') : ?>
```

to:

```
<?php if ($link == 1 || $link == 2) : ?>
```

There are other (perhaps better) ways to achieve what you're trying to do, but that should fix the link at least.

Edit: oh, and, you need to change these two lines:

```
<?php if ($link == '1') {?>
<?php elseif ($link == '2') {?>
```

to:

```
<?php if ($link == '1') : ?>
<?php elseif ($link == '2') : ?>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, that fixed all the syntax errors. But for some reason, which is why I believe I ended up with the code I did, the second <a href> line goes black in DW.

Answer (score 2):

```
 ------------------- Controller.php --------------------

 <?php

  $class = 'gthumb';   
  if($link == 1) $class = '';   
  /* else if, init other vars, etc */   
  require "View.php"; 

 ------------------- View.php ---------------------------
 <?php

  <a class="<?php echo $class; ?>" href="<?php echo $url; ?>"
   title="<?php echo $title; ?>" />

 --------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Again thank you, this is all in my functions file. Im trying this now.

Answer (score -1):

This is a matter of taste, but I like to write my mixed html/php like this:

```
if ($link == '1')
    echo '<a class="gthumb" href="'.$img_url.'" title="'.$img_title.'">';
elseif ($link == '2')
    echo '<a href="'.$img_url.'" title="'.$img_title.'">';
```